# table as var in cur.execute

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm noob at python, and I'm trying to do some operations in some tables.
At the moment I'm doing this with hard coding the tables:

```
cur.execute("select id,email from table1;")
```

but I'm want to change the tables to and variable to construct a function, like:

```
cur.execute("select id,email from table;")
```

How I can do this?

Many thanks

I'm using `python3` with `psycopg2`

```
    #open connection with db
    conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="test", user="test", password="test")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    #Select id
    cur.execute("select id,email from customers;")
    #put ids on list
    row = cur.fetchone()
```

Also I tried this:

```
    sql = "select id,email from %s"
    val = customers
    cur.execute(sql, val)
```

And I have this error:

````
File "updateemails.py", line 14, in <module>
    val = (customers)
NameError: name 'customers' is not defined```
````

Comment: Before using `PsycoPG` learn more about [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Comment: thanks, but I need to do some operation with the information, i can't do this with psql.

Comment: `sql = "select * from %s" % "customers"` ? If you noob in the Python (I am noob too) anything in the Python is [objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) Including string constants. So methods is available. for example `"{foo}".format(foo='bar')`